# Yet another infamous FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE problem

Tags: java, android

I am really sorry I have to ask this, but I have read all the similar questions and answers and I couldn't solve my problem.

I am not a programmer. I have an app that has been written in Java by a guy, whom I can not reach anymore.

I updated everything, like Firebase for SDK 32 except ExoPlayer. If I update exoplayer, the app crashes immediately.

If I don't update exoplayer, I get the eror in the title in two cases.

I added implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.7.1' already and I tried everything I could find on the internet, but my basic understanding about programming is not enough.

If I search for "PendingIntent" I get this:

[image]

It would be nice if somebody could point me into the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.mycompany.myapp.services.BKDMobileMediaBrowserService: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.mycompany.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4953)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:310)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2300)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

And

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.mycompany.myapp: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
       at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
       at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:557)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:528)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:492)
       at android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat.<init>(MediaSessionCompat.java:466)
       at com.mycompany.myapp.services.BKDMobileMediaBrowserService.onCreate(BKDMobileMediaBrowserService.java:471)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4940)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:310)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2300)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Unfortunately I can not paste the BKDMobileMediaBrowserService code here, because it's too long, but I have this in it. I assume this should be changed somehow:

```
private PendingIntent createContentIntent() {
        Intent openUI = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        openUI.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, REQUEST_CODE, openUI, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    }
```

Comment: Replace `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` in your `PendingIntent.getActivity()` call.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately it didn't help. I added an image to the post above. That's what I get when I search for PendingIntent. MAybe I have to add that in more places?

Comment: That, and perhaps update ExoPlayer.

Comment: As I said, Every time I update ExoPlayer in buildGradle, the app crashes on build. I get things like this: "error: cannot find symbol
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerFactory;
                                    ^
  symbol:   class ExoPlayerFactory
  location: package com.google.android.exoplayer2"

Many of them.

Comment: The API changed between the ExoPlayer you have and the now-current ExoPlayer.

Comment: Ok, thanks! That's important to know.

Comment: @Netuddki you need to change the flags everywhere

Comment: @Netuddki also you need to change the imports after the new exo player version

Comment: @CommonsWare can you check my question as well